# Facebook sharing for multi tenant web application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-javascript-sdk, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant web application and I'm wondering which would be the best way to let all the tenant publish their content on the feed of their facebook page (if they have one of course).
There's no public page/link to share so all the shared content has to go straight to the feed (using JS with FB.api feed + photos...). I am wondering which is the most proper way to accomplish this task: having one FB app for every tenant, or using the same FB app for all the different pages, or some other way...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would set this up using a Facebook app for each tenant. This would be forward thinking if you ever want to do further Facebook integration. This also protects your tenants from eachother's behavior. If one tenant violates Facebook policy (There's a lot more of it nowadays) and gets their app locked or anything similar then it won't affect your other tenants ability to interact with Facebook. Also if your application is a white label app then giving each tenant their own Facebook app is almost necessary. Of course each clients having their own app does incur maintenance costs. Whenever Facebook decides to deprecate functionality or implement new features that require their Migration strategies, you'll have to manage each of the apps individually at developers.facebook.com, and depending on how many tenants you have and which features you've integrated with, that can be become tedious since there's no way of automating confirmation of compliance for all of the apps set up. Also now there's a review process for a lot of integration features. That review process would be required for each of the apps individually depending on the features implemented.